# Rails - ActiveAdmin - filter spanning relationship and using method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, activeadmin

I have a User and Wallet models.

```
class Wallet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wallet_usages
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :wallet

  def full_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}".strip
  end
end
```

I'd like to add a filter in wallet's active admin `index` page, to filter wallets by user's `:full_name`

The closest I went is:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Wallet do
  filter :user_last_name, as: :string
end
```

If I try something like: `filter :user_full_name, as: :string` I get

> undefined method `user_full_name_contains' for Ransack::Search>:Ransack::Search

How can I use that method for filtering?

Answer (score 1):

Not *exactly* what I was looking for, since it does not use the `:full_name` method, but the following provides analogous results:

```
filter :user_first_name_or_user_last_name_cont, label: 'User Full Name'
```